# Picking random data with sample() from python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there anyway to pick random data from a dataframe?
df.sample() used to pick a random row/columns. I want to create a dataframe consists of random sample from a dataframe but not taking it by row/column

example

| col 0 | col 1 | col 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 3 |
| 2 | 6 | 2 |
| 3 | 7 | 4 |
| 4 | 8 | 9 |

i want to turn it into

| col 0 | col 1 | col 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | 7 | 1 |
| 4 | 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 8 |
| 5 | 6 | 4 |

you put a random data to a new dataframe from a random range in a dataframe

Comment: What's the connection between input and output?

Comment: i pick random data from the input then place it into a new dataframe. basically like df.sample() do but i don't want to take the whole row/columns, i just want to grab random 1x1 data until NxN matrix fullfilled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going to numpy, shuffling there, putting it back to a dataframe:

```
import numpy as np

vals = df.to_numpy().ravel()
np.random.shuffle(vals)

new = pd.DataFrame(vals.reshape(df.shape), index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
```

to get

```
>>> new

   col 0  col 1  col 2
0      8      1      7
1      3      2      6
2      5      9      4
3      4      3      2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple `np.random.shuffle()`:

```py
np.random.shuffle(df.values)
print(df)
```

Prints (for example):

```
   col 0  col 1  col 2
0      3      7      4
1      1      5      3
2      2      6      2
3      4      8      9
```